The share link will not clear in Firefox settings
I went to right-click on a open tab to share it with somebody. The share link has many unwanted choices. I wanted to clear those. So I went to Firefox settings Cookies and Site Data to clear everything in the cache, but it will not remove them. Any help greatly appreciated.


Are those email addresses in your list of Contacts? On Windows, it uses the global Windows Contact list.

It appears these are all emails I responded to at one time. I no longer need to communicate with these people. I've searched contacts, other contacts and can't find where they're located to delete them.

These are personal emails in nature, not part of an organization.

I've search my current profile, I've searched for data files with @ and contact that might store email addresses. Here are two places to look with JSON or SQLLite editor: autofill-profiles.json. formhistory.sqlite,

Unfortunately, I did not have any luck with that. However, upon further review it seems these previous email addresses are coming from outlook.com. I logged into my account went to addresses other accounts etc. they don't show up. But if I create a new email and I type the first letter like a b or c they'll show up as a selection to choose from. So it appears one way or another Firefox is gathering previous email entries from some place where I can choose to share link with them.
